# Sequelize - Mysql foreignKey ADD CONSTRAINT fails with ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, alter

I'm trying to create two tables with the following model of Sequelize:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (db) {
const Product = db.define('product', {
    intProductID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false

    },
    strName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    douPrice: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE
    }
});

return Product;
}

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(db){
const User = db.define('user', {
    intUserID:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    strEmail:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING
    },

    strPassword:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING
    },

    strFirstName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    strLastName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

return User;
}
```

After adding these two models, I try to associate them with the follow code:

```
Product.belongsTo(
        User,
        {
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'intCreateUserID',
                allowNull: false
            },
            foreignKeyConstraint: true
        }
    );
```

The first time this happens, it works well. But after one time, it tries to add the constraints several time. I'm continuously getting the following error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Can't create table 'shop.#sql-4d23_2563b' (errno: 121)
code: 'ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE',
 errno: 1005,
 sqlState: '#HY000',
 sql: 'ALTER TABLE `products` ADD CONSTRAINT `products_intUpdateUserID_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`intUpdateUserID`) REFERENCES `users` (`intUserID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;'
```

I tried to reproduce the error on mysql console and copy paste the query. I noticed that it fails because of the existing foreign key. It tries to re-add the constrain without removing it first. Is this a bug of Sequelize or is my definition of model wrong?

I'm syncing the tables with the follow code:

```
init.db.sync({ alter: true }).then(() => {
    proceed();
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After updated to the latest version of Sequelize the problem was solved. People who are getting the same error could try to update the version.